# python: subprocess throws unterminated `s' error

Tags: python

I have existing code that needs some modifications. I could not find a better & easier way to do it in python & can achieve what i want using unix. So im trying to add subprocess in the code & it throws error.

```
subprocess.call(['sed', '-i', '-e',  ':a;/"$/{P;D};N;s/\n//g;ba', file1])
```

The above is the code and the error i get is

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command
```

what am i doing incorrect?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ok, so first thing, your string is indeed incomplete, because the `\n` character gets escaped by python *before* passing through to `sed` which makes a line feed within your sed rule, making it indeed incomplete. TO fix that:

```
subprocess.call(['sed', '-i', '-e',  ':a;/"$/{P;D};N;s/\\n//g;ba', file1])
```

That being said, you should be able to achieve the same using basic python string manipulation and PCRE.

Comment: How else can i do this? The thing is i need to cleanup the file without creating a new file i.e., in place..

Comment: well, if you tell exactly what the command does, or even better: what you want/need, I can give you a pythonic way of doing it. I haven't done full sed stuff in a while :)

Answer (score 2):

The '\n' in the middle of your *s/\n//g* command is being evaluated as an actual newline by python, which *sed* is interpreting as the end of the command. You need to either escape the backslash or (probably better) use raw string syntax:

```
subprocess.call(['sed', '-i', '-e',  r':a;/"$/{P;D};N;s/\n//g;ba', file1])
```